# How to compare a list with dataframe column headers and substitute the header's name?

Tags: python, pandas, list

There is a df

```
df_example =

id   city    street       house   flat
0    NY      street_ny    111     01
1    LA      street_la    222     02
2    SF      street_sf    333     03
3    Vegas   street_vg    444     04
4    Boston  street_bs    555     05
```

And in a database exists a table where every column name matches with column id (withoit id column)

```
sql_table (as df) = 

column_name   column_id
city          0
street        1
house         2
flat          3
```

I need to substitute in df_example column names with column ids from sql_table

Like this

```
id   0       1            2       3
0    NY      street_ny    111     01
1    LA      street_la    222     02
2    SF      street_sf    333     03
3    Vegas   street_vg    444     04
4    Boston  street_bs    555     05
```

So far I got the list of column names  without id column name

```
column_names_list = list(df_example)[1:]

column_names_list = ['city', 'street', 'house', 'flat']
```

But how to proceed I have no idea

.isin method doesn't really what I need

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rename` with dictionary created by `zip`:

```
df_example = df_example.rename(columns=dict(zip(df['column_name'], df['column_id'])))
print (df_example)
   id       0          1    2  3
0   0      NY  street_ny  111  1
1   1      LA  street_la  222  2
2   2      SF  street_sf  333  3
3   3   Vegas  street_vg  444  4
4   4  Boston  street_bs  555  5
```

Comment: Super, exactly what I need! Thanks!